# Expanding CodeMap as output from Architecture in vs2017

Tags: code-map

How to view the complete expanded DGML generated from Architecure - CodeMap menu , till fields/methods.
For each level currently we are required to select and click on expand in Group menu and it expands one level.

How to drill down to all levels at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, you have to expand level by level. The reason we didn't put something like this in the product was that as you drill down more and more graph elements are created on the screen and it becomes unmanageable / unusable fast.

Alternatively, there are a few code queries you can use, if you right click on a class etc. you see options such as "Show all classes derived from this" etc.